# Formatação correta para data

Tags: angularjs

Estou formatando a data início de uma lista conforme o código abaixo, sendo que no banco de dados as datas cadastradas em "2018-11-01" e "2018-11-02" estão sendo listadas respectivamente com as datas em "31/10/2018" e "01/11/2018" na tela.

código no frontend:

```
{{material.dataInicio | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
```

Obs.: As demais datas estão corretas.

Comment: Tenta assim: `{{ material.dataInicio | date: 'dd/MM/yyy' | 'UTC' }}`

Comment: @Sorack, tentei o procedimento, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Qual sua versão do angularjs?

Comment: @Sorack, a versão é a 1.7.x

Comment: @Sorack, o negócio é que algumas datas estão exibindo datas diferentes das cadastradas na base. 
Exemplos: 2018-11-01 na base e na listagem 31/10/2018 ou na base 2018-11-02, na listagem 01-11-2018. É como se tirasse o último dia, mas demais datas, ficam todos normais.

Comment: Quando você dá um `console.log(material.dataInicio)` aparece o que no console?

Comment: Meu palpite é que fuso horário configurado no banco não é o mesmo do frontend, daí a diferença (palpite baseado em nada, pq eu não sei como o angular trabalha com datas). Se puder por favor **[edit]** a pergunta colocando os tipos do campo, tanto no banco quanto no frontend, além dos valores e da mensagem de erro que vc mencionou no comentário abaixo, talvez nos dê mais pistas do que pode ser

Comment: @hkotsubo, consegui resolver pelo backend. Utilizando o SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); Criei um atributo private transient String dataInicioStr; Depois passei esta string do SimpleDateFormat => material.setDataInicioStr(sdf.format(material.getDataInicio())); e resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente realizar sua formatação via Java.

Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dataFormatada = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
      dataFormatada.format(SuaData)
```

No front você pega essa String que o método format irá lhe fornecer

Comment: estou implementando, mas agora está exibindo um novo erro de conversão de String para LocalDate.

Comment: Alysson, resolvi a partir da sua solução. Criei um atributo private transient String dataInicioStr; Depois passei esta string material.setDataInicioStr(sdf.format(material.getDataInicio())); e resolveu o problema.